# Getting out of range error, while the requested item should be in bound

Tags: c++, vector, arduino

I'm working on a protocol to use for future projects on microcontrollers. I'm using the '[StandardCplusplus](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus)' library that allows me to use *standard* C++ features, like `vector`s.

The problem I'm having is that the vector is giving an out of range error when requesting an item. The thing is, that the item should be in range because the size of the vector is bigger than the position of the element requested.

The problem occurs in the following code:

```
// These two variables have been defined before (as method parameters)
// The values below are some dummy values
string s = "this_is_some_string"; // This is the string that should be splitted
char splitChar = '_'; // The is the delimiter character

// Define a vector to store the string parts in
vector<string> strs;

// Split the string
int start = 0, end = 0;
while((end = s.find(splitChar, start)) != string::npos) {
    strs.push_back(s.substr(start, end - start));
    start = end + 1;
}
strs.push_back(s.substr(start));

// Print the vector size, for debugging
Serial.print("Vector size: ");
Serial.println(strs.size());

// Loop through the vector
for(int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
    Serial.print("[");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("] ");
    Serial.println(strs.at(i).c_str());
}
```

This is a code part from a method that splits a string into multiple substrings by a delimiter character. The first two variables are defines using two method parameters, but I put them there to make the example work. I'm using the Arduino libraries to print debug messages to a console using `Serial.println("");` which is running on my computer.

When the error occurs, the following output is given in the console:

```
Vector size: 1
[0] Invalid subscript
```

Then the program ends.
The `Invalid subscript` string comes from the `vector::at(int i);` method which returns the `"Invalid subscript"` string when an element is requested that is out of bound ([which could be seen here](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Invalid%20subscript)). The strange thing is that the element requested shouldn't be out of bound. In fact, the size of the vector is 1, while the element requested is at position 0 (which should be the only element that could be requested in this case). Also, the `string::c_str();` method is used to create a char array to print to the console, since the arduino `Serial.println("");` method doesn't support C++ strings on it's own.

What is causing this error, and how could I fix it?

Comment: How did you insert a string in `strs` ? To me it could be you could have inserted the string `"Invalid subscript"`, and that the code you showed works perfectly well.

Comment: Also the Arduino is a small 8-bit device, handling std::string and std::vector is asking much out of it and is generally not a very good idea. (I don't know if this is the source of your problem or not)

Comment: That sounds like a valid cause, but I don't know where that would happen then.
I've extended the code in the answer, with the part that splits a string into multiple substrings, which puts the substrings into the vector.

Comment: Indeed I know it's a 8-bit device, but we're talking about strings with a maximum length of about 80 characters (and just a few of them), so I don't think that's the issue, unless it's caused by the `std::vector` itself indeed.
The thing is, that the thing I'm working on has worked before, but with Arduino libraries. I'm now rewriting everything to use the StandardCplusplus strings instead of the Arduino ones, for compatability. Then this error started showing up.

Comment: Mmmh it's really strange. Normally, assuming `splitChar` is `c`, it should split the string in 4 parts, not one, so there is definitely something going wrong about the code that splits the string. Since it works fine on my PC it's not a problem in your code but in how the arduino handles it... very strange. You should look closely at what happens in this while loop with a debugger... I'm afraid I can't help you more :(

Comment: Indeed, `splitChar` is `c`, sorry for that.
About the 4 parts, the actual string being splitted is different, this is just an example value. The 'actual string' contains a lot of characters that are invisible (such as control character) that's why I didn't used the actual string being splitted. I could send you the whole code if you'd like, which could be compiled and ran so you can debug it yourself.

Comment: Since both std:vector and std::string relies heavily on heap memory allocation, and that is not a feature typical of 8-bit micros, I'd look for the problem here. I can't say more though, I'm no arduino user.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definately take a look into that! Thanks again for your help.
(I've extended my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `::` does not work with Arduino IDE, try using `strlen()-1` instead

i.e. use

```
while((end = s.find(splitChar, start)) != strlen(s)-1) {
    strs.push_back(s.substr(start, end - start));
    start = end + 1;
}
```

instead of

```
while((end = s.find(splitChar, start)) != string::npos) {
    strs.push_back(s.substr(start, end - start));
    start = end + 1;
}
```